# WP - saving audio from url to IsoStorage and then playing by background agent

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, audio-streaming, windows-phone-8-emulator

I get stream for audio:

```
public static Task<Stream> DownloadFile(Uri url)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Stream>();
    var wc = new WebClient();
    wc.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Error != null) tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
        else if (e.Cancelled) tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        else tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
    };
    wc.OpenReadAsync(url);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

I saved it to IsoStorage:

```
public static void SaveStreamToFile(Stream streamToRead, string fileName)
{
    var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, file))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (streamToRead.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
        {
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

and I saved serialized information about playlist again to IsoStorage and in background audio player I deserialize it and get information about tracks. Everything seems fine. I get everything in my playList property in AudioPlayer.

The problem is when I tried to play tracks. More accurately when I hit next track button. The problem is that next song not always starts playing. When I add breakpoint for example
to method `OnPlayStateChanged(...)`:

```
        case PlayState.Stopped:
            break; <-- breakpoint is here
```

And I didnd't do anything. I just hit continue and every tracks after that is playing. But without this not every track is playing (some tracks just not start playing, there is just silence). I know it's not related to that state (or I think). I think that the problem could be with some buffering. When I placed breakpoint somewhere then the phone could do some things in background and then when I click continue it's ready to playing. How can I fix? Thanks

**Edit:**

SimpleTrack class

```
public class TrackSimple
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    public string TrackLink { get; set; }
    public string CoverUri { get; set; }


    public TrackSimple()
    {

    }

    public TrackSimple(string title, string artist, string album, string trackLink, string coverUri)
    {
        Title = title;
        Artist = artist;
        Album = album;
        TrackLink = trackLink;
        CoverUri = coverUri;
    }
}
```

PlayList class

```
public class PlayList
{
    public List<TrackSimple> Tracks { get; set; }

    public PlayList()
    {
        Tracks = new List<TrackSimple>();
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of playlist (or playlist file) are you using?

Comment: I added classes for my playlist if it is what you mean.